# How can I convert an array of integers and strings to a string, but retain single quotes around the strings?

Tags: ruby

I need to convert an array of strings and integers into a conjoined string, while preserving the single quotes around the string values. For example, I need to turn this:

```
["abc", "xyz", 123, 456]
```

into this:

```
"'abc','xyz',123,456"
```

I tried variations on `join` and `to_s`, but that's not quite doing the trick. Any help is appreciated.

I got it working with a one-liner:

```
["abc", "xyz", 123, 456].to_s.gsub(/[\[\]\"]/,'[' =>'','"'=>'\'')
#=> "'abc', 'xyz', 123, 456"
```

but I'm still curious if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When array has strings with numbers to_i converts to integer. If you want to retain it as string. I think you need to use this.

```
      arr=["123", "abc", 123]
      arr.collect{|e|( e.is_a? Integer)? e :"'#{e}'"}.join(',') #=> "'abc','123',1,3"
```

Comment: This was the fastest of all the suggested versions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following should work

```
array = ["abc", "xyz", 123, 456]
array.collect{|e| e.to_i == e ? e : "'#{e}'"}.join(",")
```

returns

```
"'abc','xyz',123,456"
```

Comment: Nice. I tested my gsub version vs. your collect version against a test set, and yours was about 4 times faster. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You should not use e.to_i == e to determine whether it's a number. Use is_a? Integer is much better. Otherwise your code can't deal with the string such as "0".

Answer (score 2):

Use `inspect`, not `to_s`.

Usually, in string literal expression, double quotes are used rather than single quotes. And if you do not mind having double quotes instead of single quotes, then it is simple:

```
["abc", "xyz", 123, 456].map(&:inspect).join(",")
# => "\"abc\",\"xyz\",123,456"
```

but if you really want single quotes, then it is still not that difficult provided that you do not have double quotes in the original strings:

```
["abc", "xyz", 123, 456].map(&:inspect).join(",").tr('"', "'")
# => "'abc','xyz',123,456"
```